# Wordpress SSL Configuration between different domain and hosted server

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I am a beginner on installing SSL in wordpress, but I'd already search for a tutorial and it seems its just easy. But the problem is, the domain of the website is on dot.ph but the files and SSL is hosted at godaddy. Everytime that I change the url setting (http to https) I encountered "[ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLUZs.png)"

If you have an idea guys, please let me know. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Did you purchase and installed a valid SSL certificate prior to changing the URLs to HTTPS?